Disclosure indicator in list in swiftui

This picture shows a list view. I want to hide the default disclosure indicator that appears when I use a navigation link. Additionally, the navigation link is causing the list view's color to change. I want to hide the disclouser button and I don't want to modify the color of the list cell. How to do this?
import SwiftUI

struct CurrencyHistoryView: View {
    @State private var textHeight: Double = 20
    let listRowPadding: Double = 5 // This is a guess
    let listRowMinHeight: Double = 65 // This is a guess
    var listRowHeight: Double {
        max(listRowMinHeight, textHeight + 2 * listRowPadding)
    }
    var dataArray: [CurrencyData] = [
        CurrencyData(date: "Room Rent", currency: "10000"),
        CurrencyData(date: "School Fee", currency: "6000"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Transport", currency: "2200"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Food", currency: "4300"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Electric city bill", currency: "2700"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Fuel", currency: "2600"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Extra", currency: "1900")
    ]
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { _ in
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                    VStack {
                        List {

                            Section {
                                ForEach(dataArray) { array in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("")) {
                                        VStack {
                                            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                                SAGenericText(textString: array.date, textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack100White90, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size14))
                                                Spacer()

                                                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 6) {
                                                    SAGenericText(textString: "Rs", textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack55White50, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size14))
                                                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                                                    SAGenericText(textString: array.currency, textFont: SAFontConstants.interSemiBoldLargeText!)
                                                }
                                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                            }
                                            .padding(.bottom, 5)
                                            Rectangle().fill(Color.SAColor.colorBlack10White10).frame(height: 1)
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            }

                        }
                        .frame(height: CGFloat(dataArray.count) * CGFloat(self.listRowHeight))
                        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(7)

            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    CurrencyHistoryView()
}


Can anyone help to achive this?

You can move the link into a transparent background:
<#YourOriginalNavigationLinkLabel#>
    .background {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Text("\(array)"),
            label: EmptyView.init
        ).opacity(0)
    }

Applied on your code:
struct CurrencyHistoryView: View {
    @State private var textHeight: Double = 20
    let listRowPadding: Double = 5 // This is a guess
    let listRowMinHeight: Double = 65 // This is a guess
    var listRowHeight: Double {
        max(listRowMinHeight, textHeight + 2 * listRowPadding)
    }
    var dataArray: [CurrencyData] = [
        CurrencyData(date: "Room Rent", currency: "10000"),
        CurrencyData(date: "School Fee", currency: "6000"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Transport", currency: "2200"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Food", currency: "4300"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Electric city bill", currency: "2700"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Fuel", currency: "2600"),
        CurrencyData(date: "Extra", currency: "1900")
    ]
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { _ in
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                VStack {
                    List {

                        Section {
                            ForEach(dataArray) { array in
                                    VStack {
                                        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                            SAGenericText(textString: array.date, textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack100White90, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size14))
                                            Spacer()

                                            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 6) {
                                                SAGenericText(textString: "Rs", textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack55White50, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size14))
                                                    .padding(.bottom, 1)
                                                SAGenericText(textString: array.currency, textFont: SAFontConstants.interSemiBoldLargeText!)
                                            }
                                            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                        }
                                        .padding(.bottom, 5)
                                        Rectangle().fill(Color.SAColor.colorBlack10White10).frame(height: 1)
                                    }
                                    .background {
                                        NavigationLink(
                                            destination: Text("\(array)"),
                                            label: EmptyView.init
                                        ).opacity(0)
                                    }
                            }
                            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        }

                    }
                    .frame(height: CGFloat(dataArray.count) * CGFloat(self.listRowHeight))
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                }
                .cornerRadius(7)
            }
        }
    }
}

